# Go worker pool while limiting number of goroutines and timeout for calculations

Tags: go

I have a function that should make at max N number of goroutines, then each goroutine will read from the jobs channel and to some calculations. However the caveat is if the calculations take more than X amount of time, end that calculation and move on to the next one.

```
func doStuff(){
    rules := []string{
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f",
        "g",
    }
    var (
        jobs    = make(chan []string, len(rules))
        res     = make(chan bool, len(rules))
        matches []string
    )

    w := func(jobs <-chan []string, results chan<- bool) {
        for j := range jobs {
            k, id := j[0], j[1]
            if id == "c" || id == "e" {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
            }
            m := match(k, id)
            res <- m
        }
    }
    N := 2
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        go w(jobs, res)
    }

    for _, rl := range rules {
        jobs <- []string{"a", rl}
    }
    close(jobs)

    for i := 0; i < len(rules); i++ {
        select {
        case match := <-res:
            matches = append(matches, match)
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(matches)
}
```

The expected result is:

```
[a, b, d, f, g]
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
[a, b, d]
```

It seems reading from the results channel ends before one of the goroutines can fully finish due to the sleep. So I added a context with deadline, but now it hangs indefinitely:

```
    w := func(jobs <-chan []string, results chan<- string) {
        for j := range jobs {
            ctx, c := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), time.Now().Add(time.Second*2))
            defer c()
            k, id := j[0], j[1]
            if id == "c" || id == "e" {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
            }
            m := match(k, id)
            select {
            case res <- m:
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("Canceled by timeout")
                continue
            }
        }
    }
```

I've read other questions regarding completely killing off a goroutine if something times out, but couldn't find anything on skipping if something times out.

Answer (score 0):

I made a package for use cases just like this one. Please see this repository: [`github.com/MicahParks/ctxerrgroup`](https://github.com/MicahParks/ctxerrgroup).

Here's a full example of how your code would look using the package and streaming the results. The streaming approach is more memory efficient. The original approach held all of the results in memory before printing them at the end.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/MicahParks/ctxerrgroup"
)

func main() {

    // The number of worker goroutines to use.
    workers := uint(2)

    // Create an error handler that logs all errors.
    //
    // The original work item didn't return an error, so this is not required.
    var errorHandler ctxerrgroup.ErrorHandler
    errorHandler = func(_ ctxerrgroup.Group, err error) {
        log.Printf("A job in the worker pool failed.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // Create the group of workers.
    group := ctxerrgroup.New(workers, errorHandler)

    // Create the question specific assets.
    rules := []string{
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f",
        "g",
    }
    results := make(chan bool)

    // Create a parent timeout.
    timeout := time.Second
    parentTimeout, parentCancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer parentCancel()

    // Iterate through all the rules to use.
    for _, rule := range rules {

        // Create a child context for this specific work item.
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(parentTimeout)

        // Create and add the work item.
        group.AddWorkItem(ctx, cancel, func(workCtx context.Context) (err error) {

            // Deliberately shadow the rule so the next iteration doesn't take over.
            rule := rule

            // Do the work using the workCtx.
            results <- match(workCtx, "a", rule)

            return nil
        })
    }

    // Launch a goroutine that will close the results channel when everyone is finished.
    go func() {
        group.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    // Print the matches as the happen. This will not hang.
    for result := range results {
        log.Println(result)
    }

    // Wait for the group to finish.
    //
    // This is not required, but doesn't hurt as group.Wait is idempotent. It's here in case you remove the goroutine
    // waiting and closing the channel above.
    group.Wait()
}

// match is a function from the original question. It now accepts and properly uses the context argument.
func match(ctx context.Context, key, id string) bool {
    panic("implement me")
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I look through the repo and my understanding is after creating the limited # of workers you free up a worker if it finishes its work or after a death signal is sent via the kill channel. So essentially, we can only do something like "it timed out, so lets free up the worker and let it do the next thing."  Am I to understand there's no way to kill a goroutine in the middle of its execution?

Comment: You can kill a `work item` during execution by using its associated `cancel` function of type [`context.CancelFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#CancelFunc). This only works if your `worker function` uses its context correctly. (Please see the [`README.md`](https://github.com/MicahParks/ctxerrgroup#terminology) for the meaning of `work item` and `worker function`.)

Comment: `Am I to understand there's no way to kill a goroutine in the middle of its execution?` nop. You cant do that from an external handler (note that go rutine dont expose any sort of ID, or kind of https://blog.sgmansfield.com/2015/12/goroutine-ids/). Though, you can signal it to exit or to return using a context or some safe handler. That mean that along your calculations you have to check for the context cancellation in order to eventually return. no magic here.

Comment: Ahh I see, so the best I can do is wait for timeout and start another goroutine if it's within the blocked channel's limit. Otherwise the channel gets block and I have wait until another goroutine finishes and unblocks.

Answer (score 0):

So Micah's answer definitely works, but I came up with this, which doesn't require third party libraries. I just modified the version with a context and moved the context check upfront:

```
worker := func (ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, input <- chan string, res chan <- bool){
    defer wg.Done()
    for id := range input{
        if id == "c" || id == "e" {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
        }
        select{
        case: <- ctx.Done():
        return
        default:
        }
        // logic
        res <- match()
    }
}

rules := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
input := make(chan string, len(rules))
res := make(chan bool, len(rules))
N := 2 // Limit # of goroutines

var wg sync.WaitGroup
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background, time.Second * 3)
defer cancel()
for i := 0; i < N; i++{
    go worker(ctx, &wg, input, res)
}

for _, r := range rules{
    input <- r
}
close(r)

wg.Wait()
close(res)
for r := range res{
    // do stuff
}
```

This answer is based on mh-cbon's comment:

> Though, you can signal it to exit or to return using a context or some safe handler. That mean that along your calculations you have to check for the context cancellation in order to eventually return.

So instead of using a channel to keep track of # of goroutines spawned at any given time, we spawn the limit upfront so that we can check for timeout.